# How to run code from/to different arch in C?

Tags: c, architecture

I've developed a small (very small) ftp client and server.
Both of these programs compile and run well **only** if they use the same arch.

1. If client is Ubuntu amd64 and server is Ubuntu i386 i got a segfault (i think it is a pointer problem)
2. If client is Ubuntu amd64 and server is Ubuntu amd64 all ok
3. If client is Ubuntu i386 and server is Ubuntu i386 all ok

How can i made these 2 programs working on different archs?
It is a code problem? If so what i have to do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would determine the root cause of the segfault, rather than speculating.

Comment: Have i to post all the code? :)

Comment: No! Use the debugger (or other debugging techniques) to figure out why you have a segfault.  Then work backwards from there.

Comment: A possible problem: when doing network protocols you don't stuff local variables in the stream as you please; you have to put in exactly as many bits as the protocol requires. And a few types (int but not only) have different sizes in 32/64 bits.

Comment: in fact i think that is the real problem! (like pointer that are 4 or 8 bytes)

Comment: yes, it fails only 64 -> 32 and vice versa!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably a difference in the size of various types and you are sending and receiving them across the network. Since the sizes don't match up, the protocol will become desynchronized.

Linux uses the [LP64 data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LP64) for x86_64 so `int` is still 32-bits but `long` is 64-bits. On x86 `long` is 32-bits.

Fortunately, the C standard defines several fixed-width integer types in the `stdint.h` header file. If you include that you can use the unsigned types `uintn_t` and the signed types `intn_t` with *n* being 8, 16, 32 or 64. Another thing you have take into consideration for network protocols is byte order. POSIX supplies the functions `htonl`, `htons`, `ntohl`, and `ntohs` that convert 32- and 16-bit integers from host order to network order and vice versa, respectively.

Edit:

As Variable Length Coder notes, sending whole structures is also not portable (though it is between x86 and x86_64). If you are sending a structure over the network you should send it member by member one at a time and assign into the appropriate fields on the receiving end.

Edit 2:

`size_t` is also not a portable data type. You should pick an explicitly sized type appropriate for the protocol. Probably `uint32_t` is a good choice.

Also, since all the size modifiers for `printf` are based on the standard `short`/`int`/`long` types, you need to use the macros in `<inttypes.h>` to make the format strings. For example:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

/* ... */

int32_t signed32;
uint16_t unsigned16;

printf("Signed 32 is %"PRIu32" and unsigned 16 is %"PRId16"\n", signed32, unsigned16);
```

Your system may have man pages on these header files (my fedora system does) so at a command prompt you can use

```
man stdint.h
```

and

```
man inttypes.h
```

to get more information on the types, macros and functions defined in these headers.

Comment: Structure padding is also an issue, though not on x86/x86_64.

Comment: So, for example, i have to do: `typedef int int32_t` and `typedef uint32_t` ??

Comment: @polslinux, no, just `#include <stdint.h>` and use `int32_t`. The header provides the appropriate typedef for you.

Comment: So i have to replace all my `int` with `int32_t` right? And size_t (which is unsigned) how can i declare it?